# CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called

Tags: ios, flutter, android-studio

I am having a flutter project in which I have to get the IOS version. When I try Flutter->Build IOS in Android studio am getting the below error message.

"CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called"

[image]

Comment: Same here for me (Flutter 2.2.3, MacOS 11.5.2, XCode 12.4, CocoaPods 1.10.2).

Comment: My deployment version was set to 8.0. After changing to 10.0, the build worked (Xcode -> Runner -> General -> Section "Targets" -> select version via dropdown box)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar issue, for me solution was:

```
flutter config  --clear-ios-signing-cert
```

And after running:

```
flutter run
```

Select relevant provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this:

> CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer
> implemented and should not be called

This is just log noise as stated by Apple Developer Quinn here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657090?page=2

> If notarisation is working for you but you’re concerned about the
> CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke log message,
> don’t worry. I can assure you that this is just log noise.

This will be thrown no matter what you do, especially on new macOS (big sur).
For the other issue follow peterSweters answer.